# Ask for polygons but getting points with QuickOSM in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I am attempting to download both points and polygons using QuickOSM+modeler in QGIS 3.10 (also tried QGIS 3.8). It's downloading the points fine, but when I attempt the same thing with multipolygons it is still giving me points.

Here's a look at the full model:
[image]

And here's the String Concatenation tool:
[image]

The log output gives some clues as to what might be happening:

```
URL: 'http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?.....&info=QgisQuickOSMPlugin\'|layername=multipolygons\''
```

This made me think that single quotes were being included as part of the string, so I tried again removing the single quotes. The output log now read:

```
URL: 'http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?.....&info=QgisQuickOSMPlugin|layername=multipolygons'
```

But, the result was the same I am still only getting points and not the building outlines of the shops that I seek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overpass API doesn't need your `layername=multipolygons`, you shouldn't send it to the Overpass in the URL. It's only useful for QGIS **after** the file has been downloaded to know which layer you are interested in.

You can follow the documentation https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM#using-quickosm-in-a-processing-model-or-in-a-python-script
where it's written this :

> Here some useful algorithms in **an appropriate order**

Or simply use the `Open OSM file` which is now available.

I see in your model you are downloading the file twice. You should download it only once, it's the same file.

Comment: Re: "Here are some appropriate algorithms in an appropriate order."
Is there a missing hyperlink here?

Comment: The link is just above https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM#using-quickosm-in-a-processing-model-or-in-a-python-script and then it's the bullet list which is on the link below my quote. Is-it misleading?

Comment: No, I just misread it. I am still struggling to find my answer though. If possible can you give me an example (from start to finish) of a working model that download OSM data (shops in my case) and extracts the polygons?

Comment: Side note: Lest I sound only like a complainer, your tool is incredibly useful and I am very grateful for the work you have put in on it.

Comment: No problem, I didn't take it bad of course! I agree, using it in Processing is not the easy, that's why it is for now in the `Advanced` group. One day, there will be the easy one. You should use a single download algorithm after the `Build query` algorithm. Then only with the output file of the download, you should use the `Open OSM file` to split each layers. Not working?